# Drop rows before a specific observation in a MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of observations (`status`) at different timepoints (`dt`) for a number of subjects (`id`) in a MultiIndex DataFrame:

```
       dt  status
id  n
01  1  xx     abc
    2  xx     xxx
02  1  xx     xxx
    2  xx     abc
    3  xx     xxx
    4  xx     xxx
03  1  xx     xxx
04  1  xx     xxx
    2  xx     xxx
    3  xx     abc
```

I want to drop every observation before `status=='abc'` to make a new MultiIndex DataFrame like this:

```
       dt  status
id  n
01  1  xx     abc
    2  xx     xxx
02  2  xx     abc
    3  xx     xxx
    4  xx     xxx
04  3  xx     abc
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a boolean mask to identify the rows where `status` is `abc`, then group the mask by `id` and use `cummax` to propagate the `True` values in forward direction then use the resulting mask to filter the rows

```
df[df['status'].eq('abc').groupby('id').cummax()]
```

---

```
      dt status
id n           
01 1  xx    abc
   2  xx    xxx
02 2  xx    abc
   3  xx    xxx
   4  xx    xxx
04 3  xx    abc
```